# How to make notification like phone app

Tags: android

In samsung galaxy tab 2 when phone app goes to background, we can interact with phone app from notification. it has all the buttons and information that we need. 
[image]

How can i implement notification like this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can add functional buttons to your `Notification` just on devices running `Honeycomb` or later. Yes, some pre `Honeycomb` devices have those kind of `Notifications`, but only the device manufacturers were able to build such `Notifications` (examples for `Dialer` or `Music Player`).

To use such a notification you could use a `customView` for your `Notification` (have a look at [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)).

An easier way,(and the recommended way) would be to use [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) and use the `addAction` method, wich will add a button to your `Notification` and execute the `PendingIntent` that you specify, when that button is clicked. This will also work on pre `Honeycomb` devices, meaning that on older devices will not show the button.

**EDIT:** you can refer to this great tutorial from Vogella : [Android Notifications](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html).

Comment: As well as the Android Developers - Using Big View Styles: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html